# Adding escape character to a string behaviour in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, string, escaping

I noticed something I have never really thought about before while trying to pass a path name to a string. To put a file path in a string literal you have to escape the backslash for the path to be interrupted properly i.e I have the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Phoenix so in a string literal it will be

```
String location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Phoenix";
```

But I noticed when I read this value from a text file where it is specified like this "C:\Program Files (x86)\Phoenix" and I use a setter method the string is able to be processed fine as in

```
public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
}

object.setlocation(**valuereadfromtextile**);
```

why does java not require I escape the path in the text file? Also when viewing the variable in the debugger, eclipse automatically adds escape characters to the second string, why does it do that?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you read dynamically (from file, command line parameter) is not part of the **Source Code** where the string will interpreted by the **compiler**

"A character preceded by a backslash () is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the **compiler**." [Java Language Specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)